# MySQL server frequently shutting down

Tags: linux, mysql

I have VPS with Ubuntu 14.04, LAMP stack and about 30 small web applications on it. Installed MySQL 5.5.8. It generally works, but sometimes stops by unknown reason.  `/var/log/mysql/error.log` doesn't have nothing except startup information.

My.cnf :

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 1024M
net_read_timeout        = 720
net_write_timeout       = 720
thread_stack            = 192K
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 30
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_force_recovery = 1
query_cache_limit       = 16M
query_cache_size        = 0
```

Memory
`free -h`:

```
            total         used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          6.6G       6.4G       233M        67M       280M       5.0G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.1G       5.5G
Swap:         2.9G        22M       2.9G
```

I checked all logs for OOM messages, but got nothing.
I removed AppArmor, it didn't work out.
I tried just all.
What can be reason?

Comment: If the logs currently don't provide sufficient info, increase the verbosity by adding a [`log_warnings     = 2`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_warnings) or debug level

Comment: Done. Got nothing, after next shutdown

Comment: You really need to find some logs because without them we can't help.

Comment: Problem was solved. Although I can't explain it solution.
These shutdowns was caused by some `cron` task.
Now I add sequentially tasks and observe which causes that pornography.